# Dining Philosophers using semaphores

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I'm looking a way to solve the dining philosophers problem using semaphores, I'm quite stuck on how I should go about doing it. I've included my code below.

```
class ChopStick{
    private int count; 
    private boolean inuse; 
    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock(); 
    Condition notInUse = lock.newCondition(); 

    public ChopStick(){
        inuse = false;
    }

    public void pickUp(){
        lock.lock();
        try{
            while(inuse){
                try{
                    notInUse.await();
                }catch(InterruptedException e){}
            }
            inuse = true;
        }finally{lock.unlock();}
    }

    public void putDown(){
        lock.lock();
        try{
            inuse = false; 
            notInUse.signal();
        }finally{lock.unlock();}
    }
}

class Philosopher extends Thread{
    Semaphore sem;
    private ChopStick ch1,ch2; //chopsticks
    private int phil; //philosopher id

    public Philosopher(int p, ChopStick left, ChopStick right, Semaphore s){
        phil = p; 
        ch1 = left; 
        ch2 = right; 
        sem = s;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true){
            try {
                sem.acquire();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                think(phil);
                //pickup chopsticks
                ch1.pickUp();
                ch2.pickUp();
                eat(phil);
                //putdown chopsticks
                ch1.putDown();
                ch2.putDown();
                sem.release();
            }
        }
```

I'm thinking of when a philosopher picks up a chopstick using `sem.acquire()` and then when they are finished using `sem.release()` but I am not sure if this is right. Is it?

Edit So I've implemented this. It seems to work but I'm not sure.

```
  class ChopStick{
    private Semaphore sem;
    public ChopStick(Semaphore s){
            sem = s;
    }

    public void pickUp(){
            try{
                    sem.acquire();
            }catch(InterruptedException e){}
    }
    public void putDown(){
            sem.release();
    }
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3CNoX8wetM

Comment: I know how it works, I'm looking to solve using Semaphores.

Comment: @Strobes The new code may run into a deadlock, see the edit to my answer for a way to prevent this

Comment: Oh thank you  for your reply. Another possible way if I'm not mistaken would be to make one of the philosophers right handed? Thus eliminating deadlock. Just a thought.

Comment: @Strobes Yes, a general-purpose way to prevent deadlock is to assign a unique priority to each resource and require that high priority resources be acquired before low priority resources; in this case you'd assign a priority from 1 to N to each of the N chopsticks so for all but one philosopher the chopstick to the left will have priority `i` and the chopstick to the right will have priority `i+1` (i.e. all but one philosopher will be left-handed), but one philosopher will have a left chopstick with priority N and a right chopstick with priority 1 (i.e. one philosopher will be right-handed)

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot

Answer (score 4):

Rather than putting a semaphore on the `Philosopher`, I suggest putting a semaphore on the `Chopstick`; the `Philosopher` calls acquire on the left and right chopsticks' semaphores and releases the chopsticks' semaphores when done.  This would replace the `ReentrantLock` on the `Chopstick`.

To prevent deadlock, you can use `tryAcquire(int permits, long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` so that a `Philosopher` releases its left chopstick's semaphore if it fails to acquire its right chopstick's semaphores within a timeout; if you use a random timeout (e.g. between 100 and 500 milliseconds) then each `Philosopher` should eventually make progress.

**Edit**: Your new `Chopstick` code runs the risk of deadlock - all philosophers pick up their left chopstick and then wait forever for their right chopstick to be free.  A `tryAcquire` will allow a philosopher to release its left chopstick if it can't acquire its right chopstick after a timeout, which will allow the philosopher to its left to proceed.

```
class ChopStick{
  private static Random random = new Random();

  // initialize with one permit
  private Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1);

  public boolean pickUp(){
    try {
      // wait between 100 and 500 milliseconds
      return sem.tryAcquire(1, random.nextInt(400) + 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public void putDown(){
    sem.release();
  }
}

class Philosopher extends Thread {
  public void run() {
    while(true){
      think(phil);
      doEat();
    }

  private void doEat() {
    if(ch1.pickup()) {
      if(ch2.pickup()) {
        eat(phil);
        ch1.release();
        ch2.release();
      else {
        ch1.release();
        doEat();
      }
    else {
      doEat();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I will try this and post results when I can.

Comment: This is correct. The `Semaphore` must be applied to the shared resource. The `Chopstick` is what is being shared, not the `Philosopher`.  Remember, the problem is that two `Philosopher` objects are trying to access the same resource; the `Chopstick`. If you leave it up to each `Philosopher` to decide when it is OK to get the `Chopstick`, each one will most likely be greedy and deny access to it (each `Philosopher` wants to keep on eating). If you let the resource to dictate when it is OK to be used, the problem is resolved.